# Remove last word from string in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have a list of counties in a dataset (Calhoun County, El Paso County, etc.) and would like to return a dataset that has the word 'County' stripped (Calhoun, El Paso, etc.) Is there an easy way to do this in SAS? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CALL SCAN will report the position of the nth word, which then you can use with substr.  `Count=-1` will look from the end rather than the beginning.

```
data _null_;
  starting_word='El Paso County';
  count=-1;
  call scan(starting_word, count, pos, length);
  end_word=substr(starting_word,1,pos-2); *pos will be the 'C' so back two;
  put end_word=;
run;
```

Comment: @scott Very true.  This could easily be handled by checking what the word is prior to removing it.  Ie. only drop it if it is the word 'County' or any other unwanted word.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case you always remove the last 7 characters (the word County and the space that precedes it). The simple solution is to use the LENGTH() function inside the SUBSTR() function.

SAS code:
COUNTY_NEW = SUBSTR(COUNTY_OLD,1, LENGTH(COUNTY_OLD) - 7);

PROC SQL:

SUBSTR(COUNTY_OLD,1, LENGTH(COUNTY_OLD) - 7) as COUNTY_NEW

Answer (score 0):

Both answers are not very robust from my point of view. Answer#1 always removes the last word whatever it is, whereas answer#2 always removes the last seven characters whatever they might be... So if, e.g., there is a County name where "county" is already removed you would remove parts of the county name:

```
"El Paso"   =>   "El"      [answer#1]
"El Paso"   =>   ""        [answer#2]
```

To be sure to just remove the word "County" I would recommend something like that:

```
/* Generate Test Data */
data counties;
length county_name $50;
input county_name $50.;
datalines;
El Paso County
Calhoun County
El Dorado
Orange County;
run;

/* Remove "County" */
data pure_counties;
set counties;
length countyless $50;
do i=1 to kcountw(county_name);
  word=kscan(county_name,i);
  if upcase(word) ne 'COUNTY' 
     then countyless = catb(countyless,word);
end;
run;
```